# При выполнении click() остановить обработчики событий

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть код https://jsfiddle.net/pyjhxu4q/

HTML

```
<div class="btn-wrap">
    <button class="btn">1</button>
    <button class="btn">2</button>
    <button class="btn">3</button>
    <button class="btn">4</button>
</div>

<div class="text">
    <div class="text-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi ducimus nulla, atque, adipisci nisi quae, dolorem mollitia veritatis ex impedit facere, voluptas quisquam officia perspiciatis quibusdam at molestias libero enim.</div>
    <div class="text-block">Laboriosam aperiam sequi quaerat provident at eius enim culpa ex, voluptate eos doloremque tempore optio nemo ea totam odio error distinctio veritatis!</div>
    <div class="text-block">Quasi recusandae fugiat eius illum obcaecati facere doloribus natus ea beatae deleniti commodi, culpa quos cumque quis sint architecto nesciunt, veniam animi! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </div>
    <div class="text-block">Consequatur quis mollitia necessitatibus inventore sint quo sapiente, temporibus illum adipisci fugit deleniti fuga blanditiis quod officiis, consequuntur maiores ut minima dolore!</div>
</div>

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.text .text-block').eq(0).addClass('active').fadeIn(1000);

    $(".btn").click(function(){
        blockAnimate($(this).index());
    });
});
```

JS

```
function blockAnimate(indexBtn) {
    var length = $('.text .text-block').length - 1;
    $('.text .text-block').each(function(index) {
        if($(this).hasClass('active') && index != length) {
            $(this).removeClass('active').fadeOut(1000);
            $('.text .text-block').eq(indexBtn).addClass('active').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
            return false;
        } else if (index == length) {
            $(this).removeClass('active').fadeOut(1000);
            $('.text .text-block').eq(indexBtn).addClass('active').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

CSS

```
.text-block {
display: none;
```

}

мне надо чтобы при клике на одну кнопку пока текст растухает/затухает остановить обработчик событий на другие кнопки. Сейчас же если часто кликать по кнопкам то текст выстраивается в ряд, мне это надо избежать. Пробовал unbind, bind но наверно не правильно использую. Прощу помощи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно на классах реализовать. Если нет класса у кнопки то выполнять функцию:

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
  if(!$(this).hasClass('disabled')){
    $(".btn").addClass('disabled');
        blockAnimate($(this).index(), function(){
        $(".btn").removeClass('disabled');
    });
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bookin/a15bp0ax/2/

Можно выключать событие клика для кнопок:

```
var btnClick = function(){
    $(".btn").off('click');
    blockAnimate($(this).index(), function(){
    $(".btn").on('click', btnClick);
  });
}
$(".btn").on('click', btnClick);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bookin/a15bp0ax/3/

Answer (score 1):

> мне надо чтобы при клике на одну кнопку пока текст растухает/затухает остановить обработчик событий на другие кнопки.

Делайте другим кнопкам атрибут disabled="disabled" на время выполнения и в коллбэке отменяйте.

Вот пример: `// https://jsfiddle.net/yarkov_aleksei/zg7gyf0p/`